# How can I ensure that I'm getting the correct results from this regression generator?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, precision-recall

I wrote a simple script that generates and regresses random sample data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import sklearn.datasets
import sklearn.linear_model as lm
##########################################
n = np.random.randint(1,10)
b = np.random.randint(50,200)
X1_, Y1_ = sklearn.datasets.make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=1, noise=n, bias=b)
X1 = X1_.reshape(len(X1_), 1)
Y1 = Y1_.reshape(len(Y1_), 1)
##########################################
x = np.array(X1)
y = np.array(Y1)
##########################################
lr = lm.LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x, y)
td = np.arange(1, 101, 1).reshape(100, 1)
n_y = lr.predict(td)
##########################################
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
ax[0].scatter(x, y)
ax[0].set_xlim([-4, 4])
ax[0].set_title("x, y")
ax[1].plot(x, n_y, 'g')
ax[1].set_xlim([-4, 4])
ax[1].set_title("x_tr, y_lr")
f.suptitle("Regression")
plt.ylim(y.min()-1, y.max()+1)
##########################################
print ("Array:   {}\nType:   {}\nShape:   {}\nLength:   {}\nData:   {}\n".format("X1",  type(X1),  str(np.shape(X1)),  len(X1),   str(X1)))
print ("Array:   {}\nType:   {}\nShape:   {}\nLength:   {}\nData:   {}\n".format("Y1",  type(Y1),  str(np.shape(Y1)),  len(Y1),   str(Y1)))
print ("Array:   {}\nType:   {}\nShape:   {}\nLength:   {}\nData:   {}\n".format("x",   type(x),   str(np.shape(x)),   len(x),    str(x)))
print ("Array:   {}\nType:   {}\nShape:   {}\nLength:   {}\nData:   {}\n".format("y",   type(y),   str(np.shape(y)),   len(y),    str(y)))
print ("Array:   {}\nType:   {}\nShape:   {}\nLength:   {}\nData:   {}\n".format("td",  type(td),  str(np.shape(td)),  len(td),   str(td)))
print ("Array:   {}\nType:   {}\nShape:   {}\nLength:   {}\nData:   {}\n".format("n_y", type(n_y), str(np.shape(n_y)), len(n_y),  str(n_y)))
##########################################
plt.show()
```

and while it seems to be working fine, with no errors, I'm still concerned about the accuracy: the regression lines are always full of random angles, and oddly shaped. How can I test this? Are there any error reporting functions I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

What you observed is because your data is random. Regression is essentially recovering the distribution that generated the data, so it's kind of ironic that you are trying to recover the distribution of the random generator, which essentially tries to hide its distribution.

If you want to test regression methods, you should use some popular ML datasets available on the internet. For example: UCI ML dataset collection (filter for regression task): http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html